# Before advice not executing SPRING AOP

Tags: java, spring, maven, aop, spring-aop

I am trying a Maven Spring AOP example while studying for the exam and come arcos the following problem.

I have a simple before advice that I need to fire....

My code is as follows

My pom is defined as

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org  /2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org /xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>my.chrispie</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyMavenSpringProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>MyMavenSpringProject</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<spring.version>3.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
 </properties>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring AOP + AspectJ -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.11</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal> <!-- use this goal to weave all your main classes -->
                        <goal>test-compile</goal> <!-- use this goal to weave all your test classes -->
                    </goals>
                </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>

   </plugins>
```

I have an Audience class

```
package my.chrispie.example.objects;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;

public class Audience {

public void takeSeats() {
    System.out.println("The audience is taking their seats");
}

public void turnOffCellPhones() {
    System.out.println("Turn off phones");
}

public void applaud() {
    System.out.println("CLAP CLAP CLAP");
}

public void demandRefund() {
    System.out.println("BOO BOO BOO");
}

public void perform() {
    System.out.println(".............PERFORMING");
}

public void watchPerformance(ProceedingJoinPoint jointpoint) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Audience is taking there seats");
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        jointpoint.proceed();

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Perfomance took " + (end - start));
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("Boo we want our money back");
    }
}
```

}

And a config xml defined as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd">  


<bean id="audienceExampleTest1" class="my.chrispie.example.objects.Audience">       </bean>
<bean id="audienceExampleTest2" class="my.chrispie.example.objects.Audience"></bean>

<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="audienceExampleTest1">

        <aop:before pointcut="execution(* my.chrispie.example.objects.Audience.perform(..))"
        method="takeSeats"/>    

        <aop:after method="takeSeats" pointcut="execution(* my.chrispie.example.objects.Audience.perform(..)) "/>
    </aop:aspect>

</aop:config>

<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="audienceExampleTest2">
        <aop:pointcut expression="execution(* my.chrispie.example.objects.Audience.perform(..))" 
        id="myPcId"/>

        <aop:before method="takeSeats" pointcut-ref="myPcId"/>          
        <aop:around method="takeSeats" pointcut-ref="myPcId"/>

    </aop:aspect>

</aop:config>               

</beans>
```

And a main class as

```
package my.chrispie.MyMavenSpringProject;

import my.chrispie.example.objects.Audience;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;


public class App 
{

private car myCar1;
private car myCar2;

@Autowired
public car myCar3;
public car myCar4;



public static void main( String[] args )
{
    System.out.println("Starting");

    App app = new App();
    app.testAOPExample1();
    System.out.println("Ending");

}

public void testAOPExample1() {
    ApplicationContext context = getAppContext();
    Audience a =  (Audience)context.getBean("audienceExampleTest1");
    a.perform();
    a.perform();
}

public ApplicationContext getAppContext() {
    ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml");
    return context;
}

}
```

But when I run it it gives the following output without the showing any effect that the before advice is being called.

```
Starting
Feb 02, 2013 12:44:37 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext     prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing     org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@2b3954b1: startup date     [Sat Feb 02 00:44:37 CAT 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Feb 02, 2013 12:44:37 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader     loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from file [F:\DEV\EclipseWorkSpaces    \STS1\MyMavenSpringProject\src\main\resources\applicationContext.xml]
Feb 02, 2013 12:44:37 AM     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory     preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3d92d11: defining     beans     [audienceExampleTest1,audienceExampleTest2,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxy    Creator,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#1,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#2,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#3,myPcId]; root of factory hierarchy
.............PERFORMING
.............PERFORMING
Ending
```

Does anyone know why the before advice is not run and why it is not giving me an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are not specifying the Aspect Bean anywhere in config file. Add the following

```
 <!-- <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>  -->
    <bean id="audienceExampleTest1" class="my.chrispie.example.objects.Audience">       </bean>
    <bean id="audienceExampleTest2" class="my.chrispie.example.objects.Audience"></bean>

    <!-- Aspect -->
    <bean id="Aop" class="my.chrispie.example.objects.Audience" />

    <aop:config>

    <aop:aspect id="aspect" ref="Aop" >

    <aop:pointcut id="beforethis" 
          expression="execution(* my.chrispie.example.objects.Audience.perform(..))"/>

               <aop:before pointcut-ref="beforethis" method="takeSeats" />    

            <aop:after pointcut-ref="beforethis" method="turnOffCellPhones" />
        </aop:aspect>

    </aop:config>
```

Also refer to this [Aspect Oriented Programming with Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/aop.html) I hope this helps!

Comment: Extra: Also its easier to use AOP Annotations than XML config file you can also place @Before"execution(*my.chrispie.example.objects.Audience.perform(..))"  before your takeSeats()method